# Why can i not cast this string as an int?

Tags: java

I'm having problems when taking a value out of a list and then casting it as an integer so I then can use it for different math functions, such as multiplication.

Current code :

```
int i = 0;
while(i < student_id.size()){
    String finding = student_id.get(i).toString();
    int s101 = ((Integer)score101.get(student101.indexOf(finding))); // <----this is where im having problems
    System.out.println(student_id.get(i)+" "+names.get(i));
    System.out.println("IR101 " + 
                       score101.get(student101.indexOf(finding)) +
                       " IR102 " +
                       score102.get(student102.indexOf(finding)));
    i++;
}
```

The error that im getting is `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`. This confuses me because I thought it would have been an object. I have tried to convert it to an integer from both an object and a String but both throw up errors. How can I convert `score101.get(student101.indexOf(finding))` to an int ?

Comment: use `interger.parseInt`

Comment: i have tried this. still throws an error

Comment: Well what error? What's the value of the string?

Comment: Probably you are trying to parse a value that is not an integer to an integer.

Comment: after changing it to this-----------'int s101 = Integer.parseInt((String) score101.get(student101.indexOf(finding)));
   System.out.println(student_id.get(i)+" "+names.get(i));-----'  it throws the error of  ---------' For input string: "35.6"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)'

Comment: @user3077551 its double use `Double.parseDouble`

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear, `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.integer`.

That means `score101.get(student101.indexOf(finding))` return a `String`. If the string represent an `Integer` then you can parse it easily

```
Integer.parseInt(score101.get(student101.indexOf(finding)))
```

---

**Edit**

As per your comment, the string is a `Double` so you need to use `parseDouble`

```
Double.parseDouble(score101.get(student101.indexOf(finding)))
```

If you really want it as an int and discard the decimal, you can call [`intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue()) which will cast it to an int (or cast directly).

```
Double.parseDouble(score101.get(student101.indexOf(finding))).intValue()
```

Comment: but this is rounding up? say the value 35.6 and 20.7 are added together this could then return 55.0 and not 36.3?

Comment: @user3077551 Yep, that is why I would recommend to keep the double if you need them. If you really need an int as final value, then do all the calculation in double and at first retrieve it int value.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse string with [Integer.parseInt(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method